# Duplicate keys detected: '[object Object]'. This may cause an update error. vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

How to fix such and error and shows items from two parts of the array it once time

```
<div class="container">
              <div v-for="item,number in items" :key="item"  class="bar">
                <p class="text" :key="item">{{ item.text }}</p>   
                <br>
                <p class="number" :key="number">{{ item.number }}</p>         
              </div>
```

this is the data

```
items: [
  {text: 'Total number of CIO users:' , number: "info"},
  {text: 'Total number of attending members:', number: 'attending' },
  {text: 'Total number of not attending members:' ;number: 'not_attending' },
  {text: 'Total number of attended members:'; number: 'attented' },
]
```

and how to get data from variables and put to the array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape 'Duplicate keys detected' in v-for loop at Vue.Js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65473255/how-to-escape-duplicate-keys-detected-in-v-for-loop-at-vue-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in Vue or pretty much any framework, when looping over to create elements, a key is passed to make it easier for frameworks to re-render components
The issue you are facing is you are passing the whole object as a key
Keys are usually converted to strings, since you are passing an object
An object converted to string is "[object Object]" which is same for all of your looped elements
Your objects should have some unique key that can be used to identify your items, usually it is an id that is assigned to each object, but if you are sure your order will not change, you can use index as the key, however this is not liked

You can do a few things here
Either pass index as key, only if this array will not have items added or removed from it and you don't plan to change its order in runtime

```
<div v-for="item,number in items" :key="number"  class="bar">
```

You can use the text if you are 100% certain that there will be no items with the same text

```
<div v-for="item,number in items" :key="item.text"  class="bar">
```

Or the best way is to assign unique ids to each element of the array

so your items array would have objects as

```js
return {
    items: [
      {
        text: "asd",
        number: "attend",
        id: 1,
      },
      {
        text: "def",
        number: "not_attend",
        id: 2,
      },
      {
        text: "zxc",
        number: "info",
        id: 3,
      },
      {
        text: "okasd",
        number: "attend",
        id: 4,
      },
    ],
  };
```

And then use this id as

```
<div v-for="item,number in items" :key="item.id"  class="bar">
```

As for showing two parts of array together,if you mean showing them in same elements you can do this as

```
<div v-for="item,number in items" :key="number"  class="bar" @click="myFn(item)">
    <p> {item.text} {item.number} </p>
  or
    <p>{item.text + " " + item.number} </p>
</div>
```

and your myFn would be like this

```
{
    methods: {
      myFn(item) {
        console.log(item);
      },
    },
  };
```

You can add @click or other events to get items, to change the array you can just push items in the method using

```
this.items.push({...objectHere})
```

Please use this link if you wish to read more about keys and looping in vue
https://learnvue.co/articles/vue-for-loop-tips

Comment: Great it works. Thank you! And I have question, if I have data in the variable how do I need to do to show it in the html code?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here, any data that is stored in state (which is the object returned by the data function if you're using options api) can be printed simply by using a pair of curly brackets 
`
{{ state_name }}
`

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment I did everything by myself.